# Cannot install git-credential-winstore

Tags: windows-8.1, installation, git, credentials

I get this error pop-up when I try to install Git-Credential-Winstore on Windows 8.1 x64 Enterprise.

[image]

When I click `Debug`, I get the following error message.

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in     mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Illegal characters in path.`
```

I got the installation setup from here - http://gitcredentialstore.codeplex.com/releases/view/103679

P.S. I have Git already installed on my system through poshGit.